# To read values from file using grep/awk/sed commands from linux terminal

Tags: awk, sed, grep

i have to read values from file test.txt where it contains

```
test.txt

parameters()->getParm (&randomNumberSeed, "-seed");
parameters()->getParm( &withInit, "-withInit");
parameters()->getParm( &useTotalSpace, "-useTotalSpace");
parameters ()->getParm (unitSize, "-unitSize");
parameters ()->getParm(&randomRaid,"-randomRaid");
parameters()->getParm(&spares, "-spares");
parameters()->getParm( &transferType, "-transferType");
parameters()->getParm(&withBmicEvents, "-withBmicEvents");
parameters()->getParm(&bmicSleepSeconds, "-bmicWaitTime");

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   static beyond test (argc, argv);
   return test.start ();
}
```

The result i am expecting from text file is

```
expected output:-
 
randomNumberSeed  -seed
withInit          -withInit
useTotalSpace     -useTotalSpace
unitSize          -unitSize
randomRaid        -randomRaid
spares            -spares
transferType      -transferType
withBmicEvents    -withBmicEvents
bmicSleepSeconds  -bmicWaitTime
```

I am using this command to get my result... where i am not getting result needed. please help me to get my result.

```
cat test.txt | grep getParm | sed 's/getParm(/  /;s/&/  /;s/,/  /;s/\"/  /g' | awk  '{print  $2 "\t"  $3}'

(       randomNumberSeed
withInit        -withInit
useTotalSpace   -useTotalSpace
()->getParm     (unitSize
()->    randomRaid
spares  -spares
transferType    -transferType
withBmicEvents  -withBmicEvents
bmicSleepSeconds        -bmicWaitTime
```

Comment: Is it intentional that there is no `&` in front of `unitSize`?

Comment: @Cyrus yes its intentional !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/getParm[[:space:]]+?\([[:space:]]+?&?[^,]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/.*[&(]/,"",val)
  match($0,/-[^"]*"\);$/)
  print val,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-3)
}
' Input_file | column -t
```

---

---

OR in case your Input_file is exactly the same as shown samples then you can simply use `sub`(substitute) functions.

```
awk '
{
  sub(/.*->getParm[[:space:]]+?\([[:space:]]+?&?/,"")
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+?"|"\);$/," ")
  print
}
' Input_file | column -t
```

***1st solution's explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for 1st solution.

```
awk '
##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/getParm[[:space:]]+?\([[:space:]]+?&?[^,]*/){
##using match function to match regex getParm[[:space:]]+?\([[:space:]]+?&?[^,]*
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
##Creating val which has sub string value of above matched regex.
  sub(/.*[&(]/,"",val)
##Substituting everything till & OR ( in val here with NULL.
  match($0,/-[^"]*"\);$/)
##Using match to match from - till " including " ); at end of line.
  print val,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-3)
##Printing val and sub string as per requirement.
}
' Input_file | column -t
##Mentioning Input_file and sending it to column to get good form data in output.
```

Comment: i am getting errors

awk 'match($0,/getParm[[:space:]]+?\([[:space:]]+?&?[^,]*/){ val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) sub(/.*[&(]/,"",val) match($0,/-[^"]*"\);$/) print val,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-3)}' test.txt | column -t
awk: cmd. line:1: match($0,/getParm[[:space:]]+?\([[:space:]]+?&?[^,]*/){ val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) sub(/.*[&(]/,"",val) match($0,/-[^"]*"\);$/) print val,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-3)}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                    ^ syntax error

Comment: @AmithKotian, Hello Amith, I have tested this in bash GNU `awk` and it worked fine for me, could you please do let me know if you are running it on terminal? You also need to change Input_file with your actual file name.

Comment: @AmithKotian, if you are running it in 1 liner form then please try following: `awk 'match($0,/getParm[[:space:]]+?\([[:space:]]+?&?[^,]*/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/.*[&(]/,"",val);match($0,/-[^"]*"\);$/);print val,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-3)}' Input_file | column -t` and let me know then, this is a tested code and working fine for me. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: the command is working as expected. However, consider there is additional data present in my file. that time this command wont work every time. for better understanding i have changed the file content of my file test.txt in my question.

Comment: @AmithKotian, it should give output as per shown samples 1st solution, could you please do give example where it isn't workking?

Comment: My bad your solution is working perfectly fine. i got confused with other answers.. Thanks

Comment: `+?` is undefined behavior in a POSIX ERE (a repetition metachar `+` meaning 1-or-more followed by a second repetition metachar this time `?` meaning 0-or-1). Did you mean to use `*` for `0-or-more instead?

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `sed` solution:

```sh
sed -nE '/>getParm/s/.*\([ &]*([_[:alnum:]]+), *"([^"]+)"\).*/\1 \2/p' file |
column -t

randomNumberSeed  -seed
withInit          -withInit
useTotalSpace     -useTotalSpace
unitSize          -unitSize
randomRaid        -randomRaid
spares            -spares
transferType      -transferType
withBmicEvents    -withBmicEvents
bmicSleepSeconds  -bmicWaitTime
```

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `/>getParm/`: Match a line that has `>getParm` string
- `.*`: Match 0 or more of any characters
- `\(`: Match opening `(`
- `[ &]*`: Match 0 or more space or `&`
- `([_[:alnum:]]+)`: Match and capture 1+ word characters in group #1
- `, *"`: Match comma followed by 0 or more spaces followed by a `"`
- `([^"]+)`: Match and capture 1+ non-`"` string in group #2
- `"\)`: Match `"` and `)`
- `.*`: match remaining string until end

Comment: the command is working as expected. However, consider there is additional data present in my file. that time this command wont work every time. for better understanding i have changed the file content of my file test.txt in my question.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk and `&`, regex `( *&*` and `"` as field separators.

```
awk -F '(&|,|\\( *&*|")' '{print $3,$5}' test.txt | column -t
```

Output:

```
randomNumberSeed  -seed
withInit          -withInit
useTotalSpace     -useTotalSpace
unitSize          -unitSize
randomRaid        -randomRaid
spares            -spares
transferType      -transferType
withBmicEvents    -withBmicEvents
bmicSleepSeconds  -bmicWaitTime
```

Comment: the command is working as expected. However, consider there is additional data present in my file. that time this command wont work every time. for better understanding i have changed the file content of my file test.txt in my question.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'[()",& ]+' '/getParm/{print $3, $4}' file | column -t
randomNumberSeed  -seed
withInit          -withInit
useTotalSpace     -useTotalSpace
unitSize          -unitSize
randomRaid        -randomRaid
spares            -spares
transferType      -transferType
withBmicEvents    -withBmicEvents
bmicSleepSeconds  -bmicWaitTime
```

Comment: I do not understand `awk` as much as I'd like to, just not enough time except to learn as I need to do something with it, but I really like the simplicity of the _code_ of this answer compared to the accepted answer. Considering that this does work with the sample presented in the OP, is there really a need to go to the lengths the _code_ of the accepted answer does over this one? Is one of the methods more reliable?

Comment: The regexp in the accepted answer would just be more robust in ignoring lines that contain the string `getParm` but do not otherwise match the desired input (e.g. try both if the line `forgetParmesan Cheese` was in  the input). but matching code with regexps is always just best-effort (there are many cases where the accepted answer would produce a false match too) so it's just a case of how much effort do you really want to put into guessing what else MIGHT be in the input that the OP didn't show in their example. The code to actually extract the values is equivalent in both answers.